# (Can't load main.ndb) ClamAV Deamon Virus signature DB Error

Tags: linux, postfix, debian-stretch, clamav, nextcloud

I installed ClamAV as a "normal" application and inside the daemon mode. After the installation, the daemon status says the following part.

```
clamd[7425]: LibClamAV Error: cli_parseadd(): Problem adding signature (1b).
clamd[7425]: LibClamAV Error: Problem parsing database at line 60930
clamd[7425]: LibClamAV Error: Can't load main.ndb: Malformed database
clamd[7425]: LibClamAV Error: cli_tgzload: Can't load main.ndb
clamd[7425]: LibClamAV Error: Can't load /var/lib/clamav/main.cvd: Malformed database
clamd[7425]: LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir(): error loading database /var/lib/clamav/main.cvd
clamd[7425]: Wed Dec  5 16:55:22 2018 -> !Malformed database
systemd[1]: clamav-daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: clamav-daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: clamav-daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

In the next step, I create the config file with the dpkg-reconfigure part.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure clamav-base
```

After this step, the status console logged the following output.

```
clamd[7558]: LibClamAV Error: cli_mpool_hex2str(): Can't allocate memory (151 bytes).
clamd[7558]: LibClamAV Error: Problem parsing database at line 47779
clamd[7558]: LibClamAV Error: Can't load main.ndb: Malformed database
clamd[7558]: LibClamAV Error: cli_tgzload: Can't load main.ndb
clamd[7558]: LibClamAV Error: Can't load /var/lib/clamav/main.cvd: Malformed database
clamd[7558]: LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir(): error loading database /var/lib/clamav/main.cvd
clamd[7558]: Wed Dec  5 16:58:49 2018 -> !Malformed database
```

You can find the ClamAV DB directory structure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSkwt.jpg).

Maybe you can help me to fix my problem to start ClamAV and the Unix socket correctly.

Comment: The database is at the correct place?

Comment: @sebix I think '/var/lib/clamav' is the correct place. I update in the main post, a directory structure of the ClamAV Databases.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating/ editing the swap memory on my Linux system and reinstallation the ClamAV daemon.